# Error: Using the URLconf defined in mysite.urls, Django-3 tried these URL patterns, in this order:,

Tags: python, django

I'm doing tutorial "Blog" from "Django 3 by example" and I got error. What i'm doing wrong?

Error: Page not found (404) Request Method: GET Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/ amd alsp TemplateDoesNotExist at /blog/. Using the URLconf defined in mysite.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order: admin/ The current URL, blog/, didn't match any of these.

[BLOG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XMawf.jpg)

[ADMIN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iwUS0.jpg)

mysite/urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include, re_path

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('blog/', include('blog.urls', namespace='blog')),
]
```

mysite/blog/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_list_or_404
from .models import Post


# Create your views here.
def post_list(request):
    posts = Post.published.all()
    return render(request, 'blog/post/list.html', {'post': posts})


def post_detail(request, year, month, day, post):
    post = get_list_or_404(Post, slug=post, status='published', publish__year=year, publish__month=month,
                           publish__day=day)
    return render(request, 'blog/post/detail.html', {'post': post})
```

mysite/blog/admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Post


# Register your models here.
@admin.register(Post)
class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('title', 'slug', 'author', 'publish', 'status')
    list_filter = ('status', 'created', 'publish', 'author')
    search_fields = ('title', 'body')
    prepopulated_fields = {'slug':('title',)}
    raw_id_fields = ('author',)
    date_hierarchy = 'publish'
    ordering = ('status', 'publish')
```

mysite/mysite/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path, include

from mysite.blog import admin
from . import views

app_name = 'blog'

urlpatterns = [
    # post views

    path('', views.post_list, name='post_list'),
    path('<int:year>/<int:month>/<int:day>/<slug:post>/',
         views.post_detail, name='post_detail'),
]
```

mysite/blog/models

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.urls import reverse


# Create your models here.

class PublishedManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().filter(status='published')


class Post(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        ('draft', 'Draft'),
        ('published', 'Published'),
    )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, unique_for_date='publish')
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                               related_name='blog_posts')
    body = models.TextField()
    publish = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default='draft')
    object = models.Manager()
    published = PublishedManager()

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('blog:post_detail', args=[self.publish.year, self.publish.month, self.publish.day, self.slug])

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-publish',)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Answer (score 0):

The first error of the template not found is because of its path is not specified in the `settings.py` file.
And second one is because of you have not specified `/` path in your `mysite/urls.py`

If you want more explanation, feel free to ask.

Comment: thank you very much. But I how to change it first one?   I must to change this ?  INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'blog.apps.BlogConfig',
]

Comment: How to add the path to the tempelates folder in the settings folder.?

Comment: There is `TEMPLATES` variable in your file, you can add in `DIRS` in that.<br>Refer to this link for detailed explanation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/overriding-templates/